# How to select a single cell in a pandas dataframe by condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2,[4,6,8]],[3,[6,9]],[5,[10]],[7,[]]],columns = ['A','B'])
    A   B
0   2   [4, 6, 8]
1   3   [6, 9]
2   5   [10]
3   7   []
```

And I would like to append the lists using a condition on the first column. For instance adding 12 in the cell `df.ix[1,'B']`. For this the following works:

```
df.ix[1,'b'].append(12)
```

But now I don't know the index of the row, just a condition on the value in the `A` column. Using slicing yields a dataframe instead of the cell, therefore I can't append the value of the cell like before. (Note that the velues in `A` are unique, no duplicates)

```
df.ix[df.A == 3,'B'].append(12)

TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object
```

So my question is the following:
How can I append the list in this cell using a condition on the `A` column value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leverage that pandas will use the `+` operator as it's defined for the underlying objects.  In this case `[10] + [12]` is `[10, 12]`.  The conditional I used was just to illustrate that it isn't required to be for just one row.

```
df.loc[df.A > 4, 'B'] += [12]
print(df)

   A          B
0  2  [4, 6, 8]
1  3     [6, 9]
2  5   [10, 12]
3  7       [12]
```

If by chance some your `B` column are not `lists`, we can make them so with a function.

```
def listify(x):
    try:
        return list(x)
    except:
        return [x]

df.B = df.B.apply(listify)
```

***Example***

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[2,[4,6,8]],[3,[6,9]],[5,[10]],[7,[]], [9, 1]],
    columns = ['A','B'])

print(df)

   A          B
0  2  [4, 6, 8]
1  3     [6, 9]
2  5       [10]
3  7         []
4  9          1
```

If we try my suggestion, we get

>
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Once we `listify`

```
df.B = df.B.apply(listify)
print(df)

   A          B
0  2  [4, 6, 8]
1  3     [6, 9]
2  5       [10]
3  7         []
4  9        [1]
```

Now we can

```
df.loc[df.A > 4, 'B'] += [12]
print(df)

   A          B
0  2  [4, 6, 8]
1  3     [6, 9]
2  5   [10, 12]
3  7       [12]
4  9    [1, 12]
```

Comment: I am getting `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list` error

Comment: @VivekSable one of your column elements must be an integer.  If that is the case, this won't work.  You'll need to be a bit more clever.  If this is the case, please edit your question with more complete requirements so that we can answer appropriately.

Comment: no, I am using same dataframe from question. all values from column "B" are list type.

Comment: @VivekSable what version of pandas are you using?  `pd.__version__`

Comment: version is `0.15.2`

Comment: I'll have to check later... that may be the problem.  I'm on `0.19`

Comment: upgrading to  0.19, let see

Comment: @piRSquared actually I get the same error with the dataframe I put in the question. So there is no integer in the column, only lists. But I guess it's a version error since I don't have listify either. I might update since this would work very fine. Thank you

Comment: @ysearka I wrote `listify`.  It's included in the post.

Comment: @piRSquared I know, and it's not recognized by my older version of pandas: `NameError: name 'listify' is not defined`. Thank you anyway for your answer, it's precise and efficient.

Comment: @piRSquared: Its work with pandas `0.19.2`  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is not normal operation to store lists in a df, but here you need the index label of the Series so you can then `append`:

```
In [68]:
idx = df.loc[df['A'] == 3,'B'].index[0]
df.loc[df['A'] == 3,'B'][idx].append(12)
df

Out[68]:
   A           B
0  2   [4, 6, 8]
1  3  [6, 9, 12]
2  5        [10]
3  7          []
```

Here `df.loc[df['A'] == 3, 'B']` returns a `Series`:

```
In [70]:
df.loc[df['A'] == 3,'B']

Out[70]:
1    [6, 9]
Name: B, dtype: object
```

The element stored here needs to be dereferenced using the index label:

```
In [71]:
df.loc[df['A'] == 3,'B'][1]

Out[71]:
[6, 9]
```

So you need to figure out the index label:

```
In [72]:
df.loc[df['A'] == 3,'B'].index[0]

Out[72]:
1
```

So you can then dereference the list and `append`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think about selecting within the index with `index[0]`. Would a dictionnary be more efficient for this matter?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by efficient, also on what you're trying to do, generally speaking it's more optimal to use pandas to store scalar values rather than array like values. The reason is that you lose the vectorised methods that pandas offers when you're using pure scalar values